# Can you help me in Oracle to insert only time (hh:mi) sent as VARCHAR2 parameter to a procedure into a DATE field?

Tags: oracle

While writing a procedure, I am stuck at how to insert a `VARCHAR2` (which holds only hours and minutes) in a `DATE` column (which has to store my time for future reference).

Answer (score 1):

In your `insert` statement, for your `time` field, use:

```
to_date(yourInputParam, 'hh:mi')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input uses the 24-hour clock (e.g. "22:00"):

```
INSERT INTO desttable (thedate)
SELECT TO_DATE(thevarchar, 'HH24:MI')
FROM sourcetable;
```

If the input uses a 12-hour clock (e.g. "10:00pm") change the date format to `'HH:MIpm'`.